# How to stop Steam from showing all free games in library

Tags: steam

It appears that Steam has made a change so that all Free-to-Play games now show up in your library regardless of whether you have requested them.  This really clutters up the library and makes it hard to find the games I actually do want to install.  I know I can limit my library to just installed games, but I'd rather have it go back to the way it was, only showing games I have purchased.  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Excellent question! Also, I'm glad I'm not the only one that had to deal with this today (sorry!). I ended up setting mine in a separate category, and then minimizing said category.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have too many games to notice, but this is annoying.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of a few moments ago, the answer is "Restart and update Steam". This was a bug, which Valve has fixed; the moment you restart Steam so it can update again, the games should be removed from your library if they never belonged there in the first place.

Comment: y,updating fixed it for me also...too bad,really liked seeing them xD

Comment: i'm sure it's a "oops, sorry for this bug, we really didn't meant to show the free games in your list" kind of bug.